# InputConnection.sendKeyEvent doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am currently making my own custom soft keyboard for android in Android Studio (currently typing this out with it lol). I managed to create and programme all but one very important key: the search/enter button (the one that sits on the bottom right corner of the keyboard). Basically the main and only problem I'm currently facing is that I can't complete a URL search (ex. on chrome) when I press that key. These are the two actions I tried with it:

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

and

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH));
```

The first one works as it should in every other scenario but this one (ex. as an enter button or as a search button in a google browser). In the case of a URL search, it does nothing.

The second one, for some reason, selects all the text of the input area, which makes no sense.

What am I doing wrong? What action should be performed when this button gets pressed?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some extra digging, I finally found an answer. Instead of using `ic.sendKeyEvent(...)`, you'd need to use `ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)`

Comment: OMG. This is so helpful. I'm a complete noob, so imagine what this means for me XD.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this answer but the proper way to do what youre asking is using the `sendDefaultEditorAction()` method, inherited from the `InputMethodService` class